# How to return the shorter of two arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods

So far I've come up with:

```
shorter_array = array1.size <= array2.size ? array1 : array2
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Anything wrong with your approach?

Comment: It gets messy with longer variable names.

Comment: If you extract that code in a method it won't be an issue. `get_shorter_array(arr1, arr2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#min_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [9,8]
[a, b].min_by(&:size)
# => [9, 8]
```

Comment: That's what I'm talking about.